# Failed to open the referenced table 'office_equipment'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datagrip

```
/*0---Deletes a possible existing Database with the Name: Warehouse Management*/
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `Warehouse Management`;

/*0---Creates a brand-new Database with the Name: Warehouse Management*/
CREATE DATABASE `Warehouse Management`;

/*0---Uses the newly created Database*/
USE `Warehouse Management`;





/*12---Office*/

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Office`;
CREATE TABLE `Office` (
  `OfficeID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Office_equipmentID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Office_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Building_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OfficeID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES Employees(EmployeesID),
 == FOREIGN KEY (`Office_equipmentID`) REFERENCES Office_equipment(Office_equipmentID) ==
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=307 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

LOCK TABLES `Office` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `Office` VALUES ('LOG1','EMP001','EQUIP21','ROOM1','BUILD1','East of Site Area'),('TRN1','EMP002','EQUIP22','ROOM2','BUILD2','West of Site Area');
UNLOCK TABLES;

/*13---Office_equipment*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Office_equipment`;
CREATE TABLE `Office_equipment` (
  `Office_equipmentID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Keyboard` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Mouse` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Table` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Chair` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `PC` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Office_equipmentID`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=307 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

LOCK TABLES `Office_equipment` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `Office_equipment` VALUES ('Equip1','Dell Keyboard','Dell Mouse','Round Table','Interwood Chair','Dell PC'),('Equip2','HP Keyboard','HP Mouse','Square Table','Interwood Chair','HP PC');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I did refrence it right and I think the keys correct too so...

Comment: Your FK goes on wrong direction.

Comment: NOTE: It is better to create names in MySQL WITHOUT spaces. Use `_` and all in lower case. Some OS's are case sensitive and some are not, it will avoid unnecessary issues if a database is moved from one to the other

Comment: You cannot make a foreign key relationship to a table that you have not yet created. Lofical really